# Output all rows that match a sql query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to find all the rows that match the `$customer_id` and output each one. At the moment this just outputs the last value:

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT product_id 
                FROM imp_subscriptionitems 
                WHERE customer_id = '$customer_id'");
```

Where am I going wrong? My SQL query knowledge is terrible!

Comment: Can you share more code? How does that single line output anything?

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation for get_var](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/):

> Retrieve one variable from the database.

Use $wpdb->get_results instead.